# Why Doesn't Go Cast 0 to *int32?

Tags: go

I feel like this is incredibly simple code, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a struct given to me by an API:

```
// Count - Number of agents (VMs) to host docker containers. Allowed values must be in the range of 0 to 100 (inclusive) for user pools and in the range of 1 to 100 (inclusive) for system pools. The default value is 1.
Count *int32 `json:"count,omitempty"`
```

But when I try to create it like the following:

```
agentPoolProfile := containerservice.ManagedClusterAgentPoolProfileProperties{
    Count: int32(0)}
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot use int32(0) (constant 0 of type int32) as *int32 value in struct literal
```

I'm sure this is a 1 second fix for those familiar with go. But:
a) Why doesn't casting in the struct work?
b) What is '*' doing in this struct?
c) Is this idiomatic? That is - should I just write all the values like `agentPoolProfile.Count = *int32(0)`?

Comment: `*int32` means that it is a pointer. `int32(0)` is an int32 value, not a pointer. You have to define an int32 variable, set it to 0, and pass its address. `var v int32`, and then `Count: &v`

Comment: Or, in this case because the value happens to be zero, `Count: new(int32)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer to int32 needs to have a memory address to point at, and the literal 0 doesn't have that. You'll need to somehow create a real variable which has a value, so that this value is actually living in memory somewhere, and then you can use its address.

It's common to write a helper function which will do as I've described above:

```
// Int32 returns a pointer to the int32 value passed in.
func Int32(v int32) *int32 {
    return &v
}
```

Comment: oh wow... perfect. exactly what i needed. thanks! (i'm not sure what the value of this is - since it's a const, but i'm certainly not a language designer)